# How to generate srp_a for USER_SRP_AUTH flow in cognito (nodejs). Not a single correct way present over entire internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, single-responsibility-principle

How to generate "SRP_A" for USER_SRP_AUTH flow in cognito (aws sdk nodejs). Not a single correct way present over entire internet. I need that to login a user.